# Formatting the Highcharts multiple-axes graph's zooming effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to implement multiple axes chart using high charts.

Ref# http://www.highcharts.com/demo/?example=combo-multi-axes&theme=default

Can someone please confirm that multiple axes graph can be made zoomable to display date wise data like time series graph

(ref#  http://highcharts.com/demo/?example=line-time-series&theme=default).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to zoom with multiple axes. As expected, however, all axes zoom by the same measure. You can seen an example in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nt3r/mhWC2/601/).

Comment: Thanks,but it still doesn't provide zooming to display date wise data, it just shows month wise data.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question closely enough; I'll look into it further :)

Comment: The reason that it shows month data is because the categories are set to months. If you use an ordinary datetime x-axis, then you will be able to zoom as granularly as the data is.

Comment: Getting a 404 on highcharts.js in your fiddle.